# Regex to Extract Last Part of URL and Before Another Character

Tags: javascript, regex

In the URLs

https://image/4x/c1/abc/5b026cdb06921e7ca5f7a24aff46512e--wedding-vendors-wedding-receptions.jpg
https://image/4x/c1/abc/5b026cdb06921e7ca5f7a24aff46512e.jpg

I'm trying to capture `5b026cdb06921e7ca5f7a24aff46512e` in both of these strings. The string will always happen after the last slash, it will be a random assortment of letters and numbers, it may or may not have `--randomtext` appended, and it will have `.jpg` at the end.

I currently have `([^\/]+)$` to extract any string after the last slash, but would like to know how to capture everything before .jpg and --randomtext(if present). I will be using this in javascript.

Comment: You should try something and post what you have tried and why it doesn't work, otherwise we don't know which part you're having difficulty with. Just writing an answer for you is not as helpful to you or others

Comment: Try using a capturing group `^.*\/([a-z0-9]+).*\.jpg$` https://regex101.com/r/efXxYY/1

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew The answer you linked to did not address the `--random-text` part of the question.

Comment: Ok, probably [`([^\/]*?)(?:--[^\/]*)?\.\w+$`](https://regex101.com/r/zDp1Ay/2) will do it. What are the exact specs?

Comment: @Thefourthbird suggested something that works, sigh... I'd rather let the OP try a bit harder on their own

Answer (score 1):

You can split by `/` and take the last part, and then replace anything after `--` or `.jpg` from end with empty string

```js
let arr = ["https://image/4x/c1/abc/5b026cdb06921e7ca5f7a24aff46512e--wedding-vendors-wedding-receptions.jpg","https://image/4x/c1/abc/5b026cdb06921e7ca5f7a24aff46512e.jpg"]

let getText = (url) =>{
  return url.split('/').pop().replace(/(--.*|\.jpg)$/g,'')
}

arr.forEach(url=> console.log(getText(url)))
```

If there are chances to have `--` more than one time than instead of replacing you can simply match `match(/^[a-z0-9]+/g)` and take the first element from matched array

Comment: Thanks! Trying to teach myself a bit regex, but this is definitely solid

Comment: @saoirse always happy to help, :)

Answer (score 1):

If what is after the last forward slash is a random assortment of letters and numbers a-z0-9, on option is to use a capturing group.

```
^.*\/([a-z0-9]+).*\.jpg$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\/` Match until including the last `/`
- `([a-z0-9]+)` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ chars a-z or digits 0-9
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `\.jpg` Match `.jpg`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/efXxYY/1)

```js
const regex = /^.*\/([a-z0-9]+).*\.jpg$/;
["https://image/4x/c1/abc/5b026cdb06921e7ca5f7a24aff46512e--wedding-vendors-wedding-receptions.jpg",
  "https://image/4x/c1/abc/5b026cdb06921e7ca5f7a24aff46512e.jpg"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough breakdown. Super new to regex so this is a really good starting point for me

Comment: In my previous attempts, I didn't have a good understanding of capturing groups, so I was applying parenthesis left and right without knowing what was happening. I really appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
([^\/]*?)(?:--.*)?\.jpg$
```

and your desired match will be in `$1`

https://regex101.com/r/gZ9kSi/1

Comment: `([^\/]*?)(?:--.*)?\.jpg$` is [wrong](https://regex101.com/r/gZ9kSi/2). [My suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961611/regex-to-extract-last-part-of-url-and-before-another-character?noredirect=1#comment102335028_57961611) is a fix for your regex.